# csv file extension hidden while downloading

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, csv, express, download

I have written a nodeJS + express server backend which creates reports and then uses fs.createWriteStream to write data separated by "," like below:

```
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(someFilename);
writeStream.write("header1, header2, header3");
writeStream.write("\n1, 2, 3");
writeStream.write("\n1, 2, 3");
writeStream.end();
```

Then I send the name of the file on server as a response to this request - so that user can do a post to request this file from server - like an "export to excel" functionality.

All this is working fine - but when the user downloads the csv file - in windows - it always hides the extension of the csv file. It downloads as a generic common file - when I open it in an explorer window - it doesn't have an extension - so I have to manually rename it and then open it. In mac it works perfectly.

I have unchecked the "hide extension for known file types" checkbox in Folder options.

How do I fix this - make the browser respect the extension of the file or download it with the extension - ONLY on Windows.

Comment: can you give file name as "someFilename.csv"?

Comment: i did give the name of the file as
 let name = (new Date()).getTime() + '.csv';